# NodeJS Unwanted Characters Written To Disk

Tags: node.js

I am sending the code snippet:
`if (typeof(email) === 'string' && email.trim().length > 0) \n  { \n...`
as appendObject into the function listed at the bottom which saves the following value to the disk:
`if (typeof(email) === 'string' && email.trim().length > 0) \\n  { \\n...`

My problem, as you can see, is that extra backslashes are being inserted into the snippet by the function as it is saved to disk.

Please tell me what to do so that the snippet is saved to disk correctly with out the extra inserted backslashes.
The following is the function which is causing the problem.

```
lib.append = function(dir, fileName, appendObject, callback)
{
  let stringData = JSON.stringify(appendObject);
  const sourceStream = new Readable();
  sourceStream.push(stringData + '\n');
  sourceStream.push(null);
  let destinationStream = fs.createWriteStream(lib.baseDir + dir + '/' + fileName + '.json', {flags : 'a'});
  pipeline(sourceStream,destinationStream,function(error){// handle errors here});
};
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you `JSON.stringify` any string, special characters will be escaped. `\` is a special character, so it will be escaped as `\\`. If you don't want this, don't use `JSON.stringify`. If `\` isn't escaped as `\\`, it wouldn't be valid JSON, and those extra backslashes will be removed when you `JSON.parse()` it.

If you intended to just serialize a real newline, then your input string is incorrect. Your input string should have had a literal newline, and not the string `\n`.

Comment: Thank you @Evert, Yes that makes sense. 
Previously I had been entering these snippets directly into the JSON table using VS Code. This is the first time I tried using an HTML form. The form element I was using was an input of type text which does not seem to accept the new line character. If I press ENTER or shift+ENTER  then focus goes to the next field instead of making a new line. So putting \n seemed like a good work around. Thanks to you, I now understand why this will not work.

Comment: _Your input string should have had a literal newline, and not the string \n._ Is there a way to insert a literal newline character into my line of text using an the input form element which is of text type? I am trying to avoid using a textarea element if that is possible. Thanks

Comment: With an `<input>` field you can't. You _could_ do a `value.replace('\\n', '\n')` but you have to be really careful with that, because if the user types javascript, it's going to be difficult to figure out what should happen if they _meant_ to insert a `\n` string literal.

Comment: After some experimenting this got rid of all the extra consecutive backslashes `stringData = stringData.replace(/\\(?=\\)/g, '');` Thanks again for explaining the problem and putting me on the right track.